# IEnumerable list delplayed from enum values

Tags: c#, enums

I have the enum class below would like to know how i would be able to send this enum back as a list of IEnumerable so that i dont see the number but the actual name e.g. "Monday" on the list

```
 public enum WeekDays
    {
        Monday = 1,
        Tuesday = 2,
        Wednesday = 3,
        Thursday = 4,
        Friday = 5,
        Saturday = 6,
        Sunday = 7
    }
```

Comment: Why don't you use the already available enum [`DayOfWeak`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.dayofweek.aspx)? For the name: use `ToString`.

Comment: If you do use `System.DayOfWeek` the first item is `Sunday = 0`

Answer (score 4):

You can use [Enum.GetNames()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.enum.getnames.aspx) to get the list of names.

```
string []names =  Enum.GetNames(typeof(WeekDays));
```